# Is is Possible to Reserve unused space in Google Drive for a Particular folder?

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud

I want to make a web app that links to my Google Drive for storage.  I currently have 90% of my Drive space free, but I want to make sure that I always have 5 GB (33%) of my Drive space available for use by the app, even if all that space isn't always being used by the app at all times.

Is there some way to create an empty folder which will hold/reserve that space for me so that I can't accidentally add too much other data into Drive and eat into that 5 GB?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to reserve storage. Have you considered giving the app its own Service Account?

Comment: I have, but the web app I am trying to make would actually be hosting accounts for dirrerent users, and I wanted to let each user link their own google account for storage.  Since it would be a commercial app, I didn't want to risk violating Google's terms of use by creating duplicate accounts for each user :/

Comment: Gotcha. Best I can suggest is get the about resource (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about) and monitor the available space.